# Why I can't put a breakpoint on a local variable that is not initialized?

Tags: java, breakpoints, local-variables

Why I cannot put a breakpoint on line `String a;`?

```
public void localMethod() {
    String a;
    a = "haha";
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

I know local variable will not be initialized until I assign a value to it explicitly.
But it is a line of code, it does something. Why I cannot stop there?
What lines are eligible to be breakpoints?

I am using Eclipse, jdk6_31

Comment: Where in this code are you trying to put a break point ? At `String a` ?

Comment: What IDE / debugger are you using? What Java version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration itself isn't really executable code - it's just declaring the existence of something. You should be able to put a breakpoint on the *second* line, which actually *does* something.

Admittedly I don't see any reason why an IDE shouldn't support the notion of adding a breakpoint to a non-executable line - it would probably have to *really* install the breakpoint at an executable point within the executing environment...

EDIT: To clarify what I mean, this code:

```
public void foo() {
    String a;
    String b;
    a = "hello";
    b = " world";
    System.out.println(a + b);        
}
```

will compile to the same bytecode as:

```
public void foo() {
    String a;
    a = "hello";
    String b;
    b = " world";
    System.out.println(a + b);        
}
```

No code has to execute due to a declaration - it doesn't reserve space *at that point in time* or anything like that. The compiler allocates a "slot" within the method's stack space, and will use that slot throughout the method - but it can reuse that same slot with no extra initialization even if the variable is declared within a loop, for example.

Comment: @ZiyangZhang: You think? What do you think happens when this code is "executed" exactly? Bear in mind that the stack space required for a method is allocated at the start of the method, not "on demand"...

Comment: My understanding is String a; and a = "haha"; compose a atomic executable commands set after compile. It makes no sense to stop in the middle of one single atomic executable commands set, so I can't make break point on "String a;", but can do it on a = "haha". I may misunderstood what you meant by "executable".

Comment: @ZiyangZhang: It's not atomic at all. You could have declared the variable a long time before. The *assignment* is atomic, but the declaration is entirely separate, and doesn't do anything. Imagine you'd put another declaration for another variable between the declaration of `a` and the assignment of the value. That would have been entirely legal - but contradicts your idea of the "declaration and assignment" composing an "atomic executable commands set".

Comment: What I learned from this is "You are not debugging exactly what you see.You are actually debugging bytecode, not source code.Some sentences which are not next to each other in source code might be compiled into an atomic set of commands".I thought about what you said. I think in that case, the compiler will reshuffle the declaration and initialization sentences and make them into several atomic commands sets. And each command set includes declaration and initialization. What's more, if a local variable is just declared and not initialized, the compiler may just ignore that line.

Comment: @ZiyangZhang: No, it doesn't "shuffle" them - it simply doesn't need to do anything with a declaration. **There's nothing to do.** I don't know where you got this idea of an "atomic commands set" but it's really not applicable here. To repeat my earlier question: what do you think needs to occur as the declaration part of this "atomic commands set"? What native code do you believe gets executed? There's no allocation (all the required stack space is allocated on entry to the method) and the assignment is from the other statement - so what else is there to do?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: I understood you point. "LINENUMBER 9 L0 - LDC "haha" - ASTORE 1" is built because those 2 lines in source code, not just one line.

Comment: @ZiyangZhang: No, you've still missed the point. Those two instructions are *just* for the assignment. You'll still see both instructions per assignment even if you've got one declaration and 10 assignments. It's *not* that one is the declaration and one is the assignment: it's that one is loading the value and one is storing it in the local variable. So, any answer yet for what you think happens for the declaration part?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: thanks a lot for helping me with this. I believe as you said, declaration doesn't directly contribute to the generation of a bytecode command. This is really helpful: "it's that one is loading the value and one is storing it in the local variable."

Answer (score 4):

Breakpoints are produced by the IDE/Compiler watching for certain lines being executed.  These are represented by line numbers in bytecode.  The bytecode that represents the declaration of a variable and the initialization is combined into one step during compilation.  Therefore there is no break point available in the generated bytecode if the declaration of a variable is split out from the assignment.

Here's the bytecode for your example:

```
public class Example {
    public void localMethod() {
        String a;
        a = "haha";
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

To:

```
public class stackoverflow/Example {

  // compiled from: Example.java

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 6 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lstackoverflow/Example; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x1
  public localMethod()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 9 L0
    LDC "haha"
    ASTORE 1
   L1
    LINENUMBER 10 L1
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L2
    LINENUMBER 11 L2
    RETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lstackoverflow/Example; L0 L3 0
    LOCALVARIABLE a Ljava/lang/String; L1 L3 1
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2
}
```

Notice there is no LINENUMBER tag for line 8, which in my IDE represents the `String a` declaration.

Comment: I think this answer makes a lot sense.

Comment: Thanks.  I added a bit more to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: There isn't really any bytecode representing the declaration of the variable.

Comment: Right, that is my point.  There is no bytecode that represents the declaration of a variable.  This is essentially combined with the initial assignment of that variable in bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

There is no byte-code which corresponds to declaration of `a` local variable, so you can't set breakpoint on declaration, only on initialization.

**Sample.java:**

```
class Sample {
public void localMethod() {
    String a;
    a = "haha";
    System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

**javac Sample.java; javap -c Sample**

```
class Sample extends java.lang.Object{
Sample();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public void localMethod();
  Code:
   0:   ldc #2; //String haha
   2:   astore_1
   3:   getstatic   #3; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   6:   aload_1
   7:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   10:  return

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints allow users to suspend the execution of a program at a particular location. Breakpoints are typically shown in the UI along with the source code. When a breakpoint is encountered during execution of a program, the program suspends and triggers a SUSPEND debug event with BREAKPOINT as the reason.
Now.. When you compile it.. The declaration and assignment fall in a single step.. First it is declared and then assigned a value..so the final step is assignment..therefore, you can put a breakpoint on assignment but not on declaration.